# Child controls blocking FlowLayoutPanel tooltips

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tooltip

I'm using a FlowLayoutPanel to programmatically display a dynamic list of items using the Label control. However, the FlowLayoutPanel's tooltip will only trigger when hovering on whatever blank area remains after populating the panel.

I tried adding a `control.SendToBack` when adding the labels and a `Control.BringToFront` on the Panel.

Is there a way to make the FlowLayoutPanel's tooltip display even when hovering over a child control?

Comment: If you think about it logically, calling `SendToBack` and `BringToFront` can't possibly be of use. They are only relevant to siblings, i.e. controls with the same parent. How could you possibly have a child being behind its own parent? If you really did bring the `FlowLayoutPanel` to the front then it would cover the `Labels`, but it could only do that if it was not their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to make a control's tooltip treat the child controls as part of the parent one. As a workaround, you could set the tooltip to both the parent control and its children *once created*. For example, you can call the following right after adding your Label controls:

```
Dim tTip As New ToolTip() With {.ReshowDelay = 0}
tTip.SetToolTip(FlowLayoutPanel1, "Hello world!")
For Each c As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
    tTip.SetToolTip(c, "Hello world!")
Next
```

If you add your Label controls dynamically (not at one time), you can set the tooltip of each control once it's added. This can easily be done using the `ControlAdded` event of the `FlowLayoutPanel`:

```
' You can add TootTip1 in design time and set its properties.
' Then, call the following line on Form_Load or even set it ad design time if you want.
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(FlowLayoutPanel1, "Hello world!")

Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(sender As Object, e As ControlEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.ControlAdded
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(e.Control, ToolTip1.GetToolTip(FlowLayoutPanel1))
End Sub
```

Comment: I build the child control set in a loop so your first snippet is the best. I was hoping to avoid adding any more statements to the loop.

Comment: Would it be less cycle intensive to use Label.SetToolTip("string") or Label.SetToolTip(GetToolTip(FLowLayOutPanel1))?

Thanks, @Ahmed!

Comment: A string literal is obviously less work because `GetToolTip()` has to look for the string associated with a specific control ([it does so using a `Hashtable`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolTip.cs,1204)) after doing some null checking. However, in a real-life scenario, there wouldn't be much difference in performance. That said, it makes more sense to use a string literal if you already know the value. I just used `GetToolTip` in the 2nd example to show you both options and so you can use it when you don't really know the value.

Comment: Thank you, Ahmed. I'm not a developer and find this sort of background information very useful.